# SSML phrasing - is this a bug or is it solveable?

Tags: ssml

I've been working with SSML for a bit with basic knowledge. Now running into a problem with Google English (United States) en-US-Wavenet-D and others seem to be unable to properly pronounce "setup". Currently it sounds like "SEDAH".
I've tried prosody speech rate to slow, I've tried various IPA character combinations and still am unable to get the expected results.

This should be a standard English SET UP or SETUP, but just sounds very odd and I'm wondering if it's just me or if someone may have insight or a solution for this.